# How to get execution time for "native tasks" (NC, I/O and Aux)?

Tags: automation, plc, twincat

I'm working to develop a performance measurement tool to improve our template. I'm using the _TaskInfo array to get tasks ( https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/globaldatatypes/714821259.html&id= ) but NC, I/O and Aux tasks are not in this array. This is the Aux task I need to check the ADS communication delay.

I'm using _TaskInfo like this (there is maybe a better way)

[image]

Then I use Log4TC to record my measures

Thanks for any help

Comment: you could potentially use the `TE1010 | TwinCAT 3 Realtime Monitor`, this is a paid for addition though. But can give you detailed information on task scheduling etc.